# How can I mark categories in a BarChart with one instead of multiple labels?

Tags: plotting, labeling

given the following data organized by year

```
y2011 = {121.68, 70.82, 82.62, 111.03, 76.9, 76.51, 86.07, 70.03, 
  72.14, 114.14, 135.51, 104.51}
y2012 = {97.19, 72.03, 116.25, 78.66, 89.94, 152.21, 70.03, 85.07, 
  129.75, 87.94, 125.58, 157.15}
y2013 = {154.21, 106.78, 116.62, 70.03, 121.69, 110.52, 159.96, 71.66,
   70.03, 89.14, 0, 0}
```

I want to draw the following diagram, grouping the data of the same months together:

```
BarChart[Transpose[{y2011, y2012, y2013}], 
 ChartLabels -> {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", 
   "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"}]
```

[image: BarChart of yearly data grouped by month]

How can I show just one `ChartLabel` per month/category?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
BarChart[Transpose[{y2011, y2012, y2013}], 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", 
                         "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"}, Axis], None}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: oh my god, answer in mere minutes, and when I try my hand at cosmetics of the answer belisarius has already done it. Great!

Comment: What about if I've set the axis to `None`? Is there an alternative to `Axis` (analogous to "RadialOuter")?